# Spring predicate jpa query issue

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data, querydsl

I am written a predicate query to concat firstname and lastname and compare with entered character.But, I am not able to get the desired result.

```
QUser user = QUser.suer;
BooleanExpression exp = user.isNotNull();
String received = "Jack Jones"
expression =  expression.and((userProfile.firstName.toLowerCase().concat(" "    + userProfile.lastName.toLowerCase())).like('%'+(received)+'%'));
```

I am not getting the record with Jack Joneas when I type in front end. What is need to be done to resolve issue.

Comment: And why should that be? You are converting to lowercase, your parameter contains uppercase and `jack jones <> Jack Jones`. You would also need to lowercase the input.

Comment: I tried it didnt work.

Comment: How does expression.toString() look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (Java) expression `" " + userProfile.lastName.toLowerCase()` calls the `toString()` method of the second argument, producing an undefined, fixed String expression instead of a dynamic expression.

What you actually want to achieve is to concatenate 3 parts:

- the first name
- a constant space
- the last name

So your last line of code should look like this:

```
expression =  expression.and((userProfile.firstName.toLowerCase().concat(" ").concat(userProfile.lastName.toLowerCase())).like('%'+(received)+'%'));
```